# "URLize" string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm getting some strings on human readable format, and those are gonna be titles of my wordpress posts. So, for generate the url for that post, I would like to know if there's some method for "urlize" a string in ruby. For example, if I have the string "Doing some test on my áccented string ", I would like to get "doing-some-test-on-my-accented-string" or do I have to write my own? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pure ruby or RoR? In any case the keyword to google is “slug.”

Comment: If you're using ActiveSupport, String#parameterize is provided. Otherwise, you'll have to write your own, though it shouldn't be too hard (or you could just rip ActiveSupport's implementation - it's just a few lines).

Comment: It's pure ruby... yeah, the annoying part is to handle accents :/. But thanks anyway!

Comment: A more sophisticated one is in the `stringex` gem called `acts_as_url`. Check out the examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309257/182590).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used i18n myself on occasion (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368857/how-to-sort-an-array-of-accented-words-in-ruby/28370805#28370805)), but if you don't want to require yet another gem you could also use `.tr`

```
string_with_special_chars.tr( 
"ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåĀāĂăĄąÇçĆćĈĉĊċČčÐðĎďĐđÈÉÊËèéêëĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħÌÍÎÏìíîïĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłÑñŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøŌōŎŏŐőŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšſŢţŤťŦŧÙÚÛÜùúûüŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵÝýÿŶŷŸŹźŻżŽž", 
"AAAAAAaaaaaaAaAaAaCcCcCcCcCcDdDdDdEEEEeeeeEeEeEeEeEeGgGgGgGgHhHhIIIIiiiiIiIiIiIiIiJjKkkLlLlLlLlLlNnNnNnNnnNnOOOOOOooooooOoOoOoRrRrRrSsSsSsSssTtTtTtUUUUuuuuUuUuUuUuUuUuWwYyyYyYZzZzZz")
```

Answer (score 2):

After some suggestions, implemented my own method:

```
require 'i18n'

I18n.config.available_locales = :en

def urlize(string)
   I18n.transliterate(string).squeeze.gsub(" ", "-").downcase
end
```

Hope this helps someone, thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the squeeze for? And you might consider using tr instead of gsub for this particular use-case.

Comment: @mwp for removing multiple whitespaces, turning into only one

Comment: Got it. It looks like ActiveSupport::Inflector.parameterize does the same thing. You can combine your `.squeeze.gsub(' ', '-')` into a single `.tr_s(' ', '-')` if you want to shave a few characters/operations. :)

Comment: `"My blog about bookkeeping".squeeze → "My blog about bokeping"`

Answer (score 2):

Won't give you as pretty results, but

```
require 'uri'
URI.escape(string.gsub(/\s+/, ?-)
```

For your example that gives

```
"Doing-some-test-on-my-%C3%A1ccented-string"
```